# OpenCV-code causes what seems to be an assertion-error

Tags: python, opencv

I run this code, but I don't understand the error and what to do to solve it

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _,frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_blue,upper_blue)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask = mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k==27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11214: error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == 0 || depth == 5) in function cv::cvtColor

Comment: Check the shape of the frame and mask. I guess `frame` has `3 channels` and `mask 1 channel` that is causing the issue. Check if `cv2.bitwise_and` can handle more than one channel

Comment: This error means your input image doesn't satisfy the requirements for being an RGB image for the conversion (`scn` is the number of channels, `depth` is the depth code, such as `CV_8U`) in the `cvtColor` function. You should check the image format your camera is returning. Setting some properties such as `CAP_PROP_FOURCC` should work if that's the problem.

Comment: Also: Don't forget to cap.release()